# How to display a png image from API response in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I'm getting a PNG image (NOT URI) as a response to my API request as shown below:

```
Future PostToGetPostImages(String pic_id,String pic_type) async {
    try {
      var parms = {
        'code': pic_type+"_"+pic_id,
      };

      Response response = await _dio.post(_get_post_image,
          data: parms,
          options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType),
          onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
            print('sent : $sent // total : $total');
          }, onReceiveProgress: (v, s) {
            print('v : $v // s : $s');
          });

      print('***** Response body Download Profile Images: ${response.data} **********');
      
      return response.data;
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      _handleError(error);
      print("Exception occured A: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
  }
```

This is what it print after execution:

> I/flutter (12777): ***** Response body Download Profile Images: �PNG

I need to know how to display this response (the png image) in flutter, I'm using this code but it's not working:

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: aptProvider().PostToGetProfileImages("1", "m"),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 65.0,
                          backgroundImage: backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data
                            .toString()));
                    }),
```

Comment: Please share a example of your json data after that I can help you more over you used a incorrect format of function.
You need to use mvvm technique

Comment: comment here with your url

Answer (score 1):

The problem here that you is not using a URL image, confirm to use a URL end with (.png, jpg, ..etc.) and also confirm it by open it in your browser.

then

to display it in you widget use one of this ways

***First***

```
Image.network('URL') 
// ex: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9')
```

***Second***

```
Container( height : 100 , width :100 , decoration : Box decoration ( 
  image : Decoration image ( Network image ('URL'), ), 
), ), ),
```

Comment: The api is returning an Image data not a URL and that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the png is like a dummy image like a 404 like the one in the image attached so you have to copy and try check it with Image.network if everything works fine you proceed with image.network

Comment: I can't use Image.network because CircleAvatar require an ImageProvider Widget

Comment: Try using a Container ( height : 20 , width :20 , decoration : Box decoration ( image : Decoration image ( Network image (url))))

Comment: Nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you get the image as a byte array, base64 string.

Here is how I solve that.

```
var base64 = response.split(';base64,')[1];
base64 = base64.replaceFirst('binary data/', '');
Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(base64);

// Image Widget which you can put in anywhere.
Image.memory(bytes, fit: BoxFit.contain)
```

Comment: I had this exception, Exception occured A: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got it to work but I wanted to leave this for future reference:

You are receiving raw bytes as part of the response; from there you will need to use those to create an image. For this you have two options:

1. Save the bytes to a file.
2. Show the image bytes straight from memory.

Option 1 is usually what you want, but if you need a quick test you can do option 2 without issues, keep in mind memory is limited. Both have different implementations depending on the packages you are using.

Here's a quick overview of what Option 2 might look like using just plain old `http`:

```dart
// MyRepository.dart
class Repository {
  Future<Uint8List?> getImageBytes(<...some params>) async {
    final streamResponse = await client.send(<...some req>);
    final response = await Response.fromStream(streamResponse);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      parsedResponse = response.bodyBytes;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

// MyWidget.dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  <... some other code>

  final Uint8List imageRawBytes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.memory(
      imageRawBytes,
    );
  }
}
```

What's important here is that you use the raw response bytes instead of using a response body (which is usually an encoded String). This way you can build either a `File` or keep them in memory to be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
  final response = await dio.post(
    "/convert",
    data: uint8list,
    options: Options(headers: {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"},responseType: ResponseType.bytes,contentType: "image/png",),
  );
  if(response.statusCode==200){
    /*final data = response.requestOptions.data as Uint8List;
    print(data);
    return data;*/
    final  data = response.data as Uint8List;
    return data;
    print(data);
  }
```

Add response type and content type in the option. You will get correct solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting the image url from the response, then you can use the `Image.network(imageUrl)`

OR

If you are getting the imageData in the form of Uint8List, then you can use the `Image.memory(imageData)`

Comment: I tried but it says that the response it's a string

Comment: You might need to use the actual raw bytes instead of the `data`. You can access them by setting a `ResponseType`. Here's their docs example:

`await Dio().get<List<int>>(url,
 options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes), // set responseType to 'bytes'
);
`